# Multiply a matrix with a batch of matrices in Tensorflow 1.4

Tags: tensorflow

I have a matrix A with the shape `(dim1, dim2)`, and a batch of matrices of shape `(batch_size, dim2, dim3)`.
How can I multiply the matrix with every matrix in the batch? Tiling matrix A seems to consume too much memory.

Answer (score 0):

`einsum` available in both `numpy` and `tensorflow` should do what you want:

```
import numpy as np
batch_size = 5
dim1 = 7
dim2 = 2
dim3 = 3

A = np.random.rand(batch_size, dim1, dim2)
B = np.random.rand(batch_size, dim2, dim3)   
C = np.einsum('kl,ilm->ikm',A,B)
print(C.shape)
Out[9]: (5, 7, 3)

import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant(A) # reusing numpy arrays
b = tf.constant(B)
op = tf.einsum('kl,ilm->ikm',a,b)
with tf.Session() as sess:       
    print(sess.run(op) - C) # prints a zero array
```